# Why am I not getting all my regex captures?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am using .NET's `Regex` to capture information from a string.  I have a pattern of numbers enclosed in bar characters, and I want to pick out the numbers.  Here's my code:

```
string testStr = "|12||13||14|";
var testMatch = Regex.Match(testStr, @"^(?:\|([0-9]+)\|)+$");
```

However, `testMatch.Captures` only has 1 entry, which is equal to the whole string.  Why doesn't it have 3 entries, `12`, `13`, and `14`?  What am I missing?

Comment: Huh. I’d have thought it’d’ve captured `14`. Anyways, one captured group generally captures one thing; you can use `Matches` with `(?<=\|)[0-9]+(?=\|)`, anyways. Or just match `[0-9]+`. Or split on `|` with `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` (is that right?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use the `Captures` property on the `Group` itself - in this case `testMatch.Groups[1]`. This is needed since there could be multiple capture groups in the regex, and there would be no way for it to know which one you are referring to.

Using `testMatch.Captures` effectively gives `testMatch.Groups[0].Captures`.

[This works](http://ideone.com/S97ypg) for me:

```
string testStr = "|12||13||14|";
var testMatch = Regex.Match(testStr, @"^(?:\|([0-9]+)\|)+$");

int captureCtr = 0;
foreach (Capture capture in testMatch.Groups[1].Captures) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Capture {0}: {1}", captureCtr++, capture.Value);
}
```

#### Reference: [`Group.Captures`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures.aspx)

Comment: This.  It's a bit unintuative, but I needed to look at `.Groups[1].Captures[1/2/3...]`.

Comment: @Jez I clarified my answer a bit.